# PHP comparing value of $stmt with integer

Tags: php, sql, oci8

In a PHP document, I need to check if a certain cell in a database (oracle, using OCI8) is greater than zero (negatives excluded via db constraints). There is only one such row judging by the fact that I'm using the primary key attribute to filter the result.

```
...
$pr_id = 3;
$stmt = oci_parse ($conn, 'SELECT supply FROM product WHERE id = :pr_id_bv');
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":pr_id_bv", $pr_id);
oci_execute($stmt);

if($stmt > 0) {
...
```

The problem is that, even when the result of the `$stmt` query is equal to zero, the conditional statement still gets triggered as if it's condition is met. The only time `$stmt` is equal to zero is when the query returns no rows. Any tips?

BTW the value of `$pr_id` is inserted by the user in an HTML form, I excluded that part here for the sake of simplicity and just assigned it a value of 3.

Comment: It returns a rowcount, not a result. I think you want `oci_fetch`

Comment: `$stmt` is a *statement object*, not the single value you `SELECT`ed. You need to fetch the result row from it and compare the first retrieved column in it.

Comment: thats it! thanks, it's weird that I can ```echo $stmt + 3``` and it does an implicit conversion to integer